# calling WCF REST service through Ajax and JSON

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, wcf

I have made one Rest service in WCF (demo) , which gives me output as : `{"GetEmployeeJSONResult":{"Id":101,"Name":"Sumanth","Salary":5000}}`

Now i have created one website in asp.net in which i am calling this rest service through AJAX JSON...

my code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //            $.getJSON("http://localhost/SampleService/Service1.svc/getJson?callback=?", null, function (data) {
        //                alert(data.Name);
        //            });

        var endpointAddress = "http://localhost/SampleService/Service1.svc";
        var url = endpointAddress + "/GetJson";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: "{}",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                alert(result.length);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR)
            {
                alert(jqXHR.status);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

You could see that i have accessed service through both AJAX and getJSON methods..

now when i am making a alert of data , it shows me output as undefined..
i have tried :
`alert(result.d.length) , alert(result.d.GetEmployeeJSONResult)` but always shows me as undefined..in both methods..

My WCF service code is as below:

```
namespace WcfServiceXmlAndJsonDemo
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    #region OperationContracts

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET",UriTemplate="GetXml",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    EmployeeXML GetEmployeeXML();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetJson", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<EmployeeJSON> GetEmployeeJSON();

    #endregion
}
}
```

DataContract EmployeeJSON :

```
namespace WcfServiceXmlAndJsonDemo
{

[DataContract]
public class EmployeeJSON
{
    #region Properties

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double Salary { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Service1.svc.cs :

```
 namespace WcfServiceXmlAndJsonDemo
 {   


  public class Service1 : IService1
  {    

      public List<EmployeeJSON> GetEmployeeJSON()
       {
           EmployeeJSON json = new EmployeeJSON()    
           {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 };
          return json;


       }


 }
}
```

Please help me out how to handle this..

Thanking you in advance.

Krunal

Comment: You should try GET request from fiddler or any request tracing tool to make sure the service is working fine and then go ahead with Ajax. Mention here if you get any kind of error in fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Change `WebInvoke` with `WebGet` and remove `Method="GET"`.

And in AJAX call.

```
type: 'GET',
url: url,
dataType: 'jsonp',
//contentType: 'application/json', No need to mention Content-Type.
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http:www.svc/Service1.svc/GetJson',
            data: "{ }",
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",               
            success: function (data) {                    
                var result = data.GetEmployeeJSONResult;
                var id = result.Id;
                var name = result.Name;
                var salary = result.Salary;
                $('#jsonData').html('');
                $('#jsonData').append('<table border="1"><tr><th>Employee Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th></tr><tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + salary + '</td></tr></table>');

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```